# Is there something like "compile-time JIT"?

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, jit, native-code, compile-time

As far as I understand, JIT (just-in-time compilation) refers to a *run-time* process where bytecode is compiled (translated) to native code to improve run-time performance.

On the other hand, *compile-time evaluation* is a common practice towards generic programming or run-time optimization. Again, as far as I understand, in this case the compiler *interprets* source code to evaluate an expression (producing e.g. either a value or a type). In this case the compile time often increases significantly.

Is there a **compile-time JIT** process where a compiler translates source code to native for more efficient compile-time evaluation? I find it very natural, but does any compiler do that in any language?

If I were to do this in my own compiler, would it be a good idea? What extra difficulties would I have comparing to run-time JIT?

Comment: Do you mean compiling bytecode to native ahead-of-time?  If so, there's plenty of programs that do that all over the internet.  Because "Compile-time JIT" makes no sense.  "Compile time" is "before the user runs it." and "JIT" is "as/after the user starts running it".  There can't really be a hybrid.  Compilation is either before or as/after the user starts the code.

Comment: Oh wait, do you mean where the compiler generates native code, and then _executes_ the native code during static compilation?  I'd expect C++ `constexpr` works on exactly this concept, though I doubt anything else in C++ would.  Compile-time evaluation for constants and types in C++ is usually not executing "code" so much as "looking stuff up in tables". (I do C++ obviously, and cannot speak as to other languages)

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I meant what you say in your second comment. C++ `constexpr` does all its evaluations at compile time, but I don't know *how*. I read that D does this by *interpreting* the code, which is 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than running native code. Just measuring compile times (clang or especially gcc), I don't think that C++ does any better in practice.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be any point. The compiler is already compiling code. Constant-expression evaluation only happens once. The Java HotSpot JVM for example only finds it beneficial to compile a method to native code after it has been executed thousands times.

Comment: Constant-expression evaluation only happens once *at every change in the source code*. That is, depending on what you're trying to code, it may well happen once every minute, and last for 30 seconds.

Comment: C++ allows you to write functions that the compiler executes during compilation, I think that's what he's referring to, if _those_ are interpreted or compiled and then executed.

Comment: For that matter, tools like `lex` and `yacc` that precompute tokenizing and parsing tables for input grammars could be considered a form of computation in advance.  Making it *transparent to the programmer in the general case* requires partial evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about — performing code generation in advance when the default behavior would be either interpretation or just-in-time code generation — is called out as **[ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler)**.

Benefits:

- **Lower startup latencies**, if reading the native image is faster than translating a usually smaller intermediate-language image
- Shared pages of translated native code between multiple instances of one process may **reduce main memory footprint**, but only if multiple instances run concurrently

Drawbacks:

- **Harder to optimize based on runtime characteristics**; HotSpot's dynamic profile-directed whole-program optimization may compile the same method differently in different programs depending on how it's used
- Total program **storage footprint usually increases**, since native images are often larger than intermediate code and the intermediate code often cannot be removed after native image generation

You could conceivably do profile-directed whole-program optimization on AOT-compiled code, but then you would end up with something resembling a "preheated" version of the HotSpot runtime, trading back the shared memory on methods hot enough to merit reworking their translation.

Comment: Jeffrey Hantin, Can you name some AOTs, like [ART runtime](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170677-android-art-google-finally-moves-to-replace-dalvik-to-boost-performance-and-battery-life) in newest 4.4 Androids, [Excelsior JET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excelsior_JET) and [GCJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) for Java?..

Comment: @osgx, I've been in CLR-land for so long that [Mono AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) and [Microsoft NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) were all that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but this isn't what I meant. What I meant is, the compiler sees an expression that can be evaluated at compile time, like `fibonacci(15)`; it compiles `fibonacci`, generating *native code* for it; it calls this function and computes the result; it inserts the result as a constant, replacing the expression; it compiles the rest of the code normally, generating native code or intermediate code or whatever; at run-time, no computation is needed at all for this expression. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @iavr Oh!  That's somewhere between [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and [partial evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation).  Constant folding is just one optimization that could fall under the purview of partial evaluation.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin Exactly, sorry I thought [compile-time evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution) was also clear. Anyhow, I know that this happens routinely at least in C++ ([`constexpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions)) and [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)#Metaprogramming), it just makes compilation so slow, hence my question.